# ExpressionEngine->What tables to backup?

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

We have a deployment process where we are required to create a “rollback” point before a release is committed to our live server.

We have a staging server where all release candidate code is tested. Now this staging server also includes all the channel data, content, etc that is modified before a release.
These two tables are identical copies with the exception of one of our global variables {site_url_https}

We will create a mysqldump of the production server’s DB before the release to create the rollback point. We will then create a mysqldump of the staging server’s DB and apply it to the production server’s DB to complete the release.

What tables would I need to backup in order to provide a rollback point before a release is applied? This should include all changes to content, channel data, categories, custom fields, etc. What tables would I need to “copy” from the staging to the production server?

I have a script to create the SQL backup file and will post it after testing.

Also, is there a function that I can call from a script that will synchronize the templates table with the template files?

Comment: I think everyone has their own approach for this.  What we do for data sync would not work for you. We use rsnapshot for the file sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of these might be moot if you're not using certain features (like comments, entry versioning, etc).

To backup all content, categories and comments:

- exp_category_posts
- exp_channel_data
- exp_channel_entries_autosave
- exp_channel_titles
- exp_comments
- exp_relationships
- exp_revision_tracker

To backup field/channel/category structure and settings:

- exp_categories
- exp_category_field_data
- exp_category_fields
- exp_category_groups
- exp_channel_fields
- exp_channel_member_groups
- exp_channels
- exp_entry_ping_status
- exp_entry_versioning
- exp_field_formatting
- exp_field_groups
- exp_fieldtypes
- exp_file_categories
- exp_file_dimensions
- exp_file_watermarks
- exp_files
- exp_layout_publish
- exp_status_groups
- exp_status_no_access
- exp_statuses
- exp_upload_no_access
- exp_upload_prefs

To backup templates and related:

- exp_global_variables
- exp_snippets
- exp_specialty_templates
- exp_template_groups
- exp_template_member_groups
- exp_template_no_access
- exp_templates

To backup member-related data:

- exp_member_bulletin_board
- exp_member_data
- exp_member_fields
- exp_member_groups
- exp_member_homepage
- exp_member_search
- exp_members
- exp_module_member_groups

To backup installation of new modules, extensions, changed site settings more generally:

- exp_accessories
- exp_actions
- exp_extensions
- exp_html_buttons
- exp_modules

If you're using MSM:

- exp_sites

Comment: +1 This is great, thank you so much! A bit late to the game, but I'm assuming you'd also need to add all of your `exp_channel_grid_field_*` tables to the content backup section too?

Comment: That's correct (this post is from the pre-Grid days).

Answer (score 0):

This really is a question the depends A LOT on the type of site you're developing / updating. I typically overwrite the entire production database with the one from staging - but if you have a site that has commenting / or other member input it becomes much more complicated.

Comment: This is not a blog site and we allow no user comments at all.